# Custom data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a below data frame

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,3,4,5,8,9), b = c("","",0,0,"",""))
df$b <- as.numeric(df$b)
df
  a  b
1 1 NA
2 3 NA
3 4  0
4 5  0
5 8 NA
6 9 NA
```

Is there a way to populate the data frame that is capturing the value in column `a` only at a specific point
Example : Expected output (a cell before 0 and after 0  in column `b` should be filled by the value in column `a`.

```
df1
  a  b
1 1 NA
2 3  3
3 4  0
4 5  0
5 8  8
6 9 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the following solution will help you:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(b = ifelse(is.na(b) & lead(b) == 0 | is.na(b) & lag(b) == 0, a, b))

  a  b
1 1 NA
2 3  3
3 4  0
4 5  0
5 8  8
6 9 NA
```